# A behaviour of normal vectors of a ruled surface along rulings

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

If $r: J \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$, $r(s,t)=c(s)+tv(s)$ is a parametrization of a surface which Gaussian curvature is nonzero, then for each $s_0$ there exist limits of normal vectors $n_+(s_0):=\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} n(s_0, t)$, $n_-(s_0):=\lim_{t \rightarrow -\infty} n(s_0, t)$ and $n_+(s_0)=-n_-(s_0)$.

I've managed to find a formula for the unit normal vector:

$$n(s,t)=\frac{r_s \times r_t}{|r_s \times r_t|}=\frac{c'(s) \times v(s)+tv'(s) \times v(s)}{\sqrt{\det\mathbb{I}_{r(s,t)}}}$$.

I also know that the gaussian curvature of this surface is negative, because it's not zero and must be nonpositive (i've proved ellier that the gaussian curvature of ruled surfaces is nonpositive). So every point on this surface is hyperbolic, but I'm not sure if it can be useful.

Edit:

Explicity it will be:$$n(s,t)=\frac{c'(s) \times v(s)+tv'(s) \times v(s)}{\sqrt{c'(s) \cdot c'(s)+2tc'(s) \cdot v'(s)+t^2v'(s) \cdot v'(s)- (c'(s) \cdot v(s))^2}}=\frac{\frac{c'(s) \times v(s)}{t}+v'(s) \times v(s)}{\sqrt{\frac{c'(s) \cdot c'(s)}{t^2}+2\frac{c'(s) \cdot v'(s)}{t}+v'(s) \cdot v'(s)- \frac{(c'(s) \cdot v(s))^2}{t^2}}}$$
I've divided the numerator and the denominator through t.

Comment: So write this out explicitly and find the limit.

Comment: Explicity it will be$$n(s,t)=\frac{r_s \times r_t}{|r_s \times r_t|}=\frac{c'(s) \times v(s)+tv'(s) \times v(s)}{\sqrt{\det\mathbb{I}_{r(s,t)}}}=\frac{c'(s) \times v(s)+tv'(s) \times v(s)}{\sqrt{c'(s) \cdot c'(s)+2tc'(s) \cdot v'(s)+t^2v'(s) \cdot v'(s)- (c'(s) \cdot v(s))^2}}$$

Comment: So what is $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} \dfrac{A+tB}{\sqrt{at^2+bt+c}}$? (Here $A$ and $B$ are vectors and $a,b,c$ are scalars.)

Comment: So it should be $\frac{B}{\sqrt{a}}$. But why the limits with $t \rightarrow \infty$ and $t \rightarrow -\infty$ are opposite?

Comment: You can certainly figure that out!

Comment: sorry, i've made a mistake computing the limit with $t \rightarrow -\infty$

Comment: Remember that $\sqrt{t^2} = |t|$?